# Nuget Update-Package not finding new versions of packages

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a product with multiple services that have many solutions each. In order to reference things across services we are using Nuget to download and reference the dlls. Since we are still in early development of this product there are a lot of changes to the core dlls and we are having a lot of merging issues and annoyances with updating the references.

I tried using Update-Package -ProjectName XProject -Safe thinking this would do exactly what I wanted it to, update all the references with the same Major/Minor version. However, it just skips over all the files saying they are updated. When I look in Nuget it clearly notices that there is a new version so I am unsure what the problem is...

```
No updates available for 'Framework.EntityModel'.
No updates available for 'Framework.Core'.
```

in packages.config:

```
<package id="Framework.Core" version="1.0.14030.1137" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Framework.EntityModel" version="1.0.14030.1137" targetFramework="net45" />
```

There are versions in nuget with the label: 1.0.14034.1137 so I don't know why it isn't picking them up. I can open up package manager and update from there fine. I just want a way to easily update every reference without doing things manually.

Comment: I've had some issues recently. My fix was to right click the solution and select 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution', delete everything from the solutions packages folder (i.e. the cache of packages) and restart VS.  Package manager then offered to re-download everything and all packages were up to date.  Personally I suspect a bug may have been introduced in some recent update (this is VS2013).

Comment: The problem really isn't that I need to update my packages immediately. The problem is that I want to make this part of a build step so all 10 of our devs don't have to waste so much time on this issue. So although this would work locally for me I don't know if this is a solid long term solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from the Versioning page of NuGet @ the bottom of the page:

> **Dependencies are no longer unnecessarily updated during package installation**
>
> Before NuGet 2.5, when a package was installed that depended on a
>   package already installed in the project, the dependency would be
>   updated as part of the new installation, even if the existing version
>   satisfied the dependency.
>
> Starting with NuGet 2.5, if a dependency version is already satisifed,
>   the dependency will not be updated during other package installations.
>
> The scenario:
>
> The source repository contains package B with version 1.0.0 and 1.0.2.
>   It also contains package A which has a dependency on B (>= 1.0.0).
>
> Assume that the current project already has package B version 1.0.0
>   installed. Now you want to install package A.
>
> In NuGet 2.2 and older:
>
> When installing package A, NuGet will auto-update B to 1.0.2, even
>   though the existing version 1.0.0 already satisfies the dependency
>   version constraint, which is >= 1.0.0. In NuGet 2.5 and newer:
>
> NuGet will no longer update B, because it detects that the existing
>   version 1.0.0 satisfies the dependency version constraint. For more
>   background on this change, read the detailed [work
>   item](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1681) as well as the related
>   [discussion thread](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/436712).

### Edit:

The above explains why you may be experiencing your issue, but to actually help to resolve it, take a look at http://blog.nuget.org/20131216/update-all-experience-explained.html. It shows you how you could use the DependencyVersion parameter of Install-Package or override the default behaviour in your nuget.config file to use "HighestPatch".

See the Install-Package section of http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference for more information.

Comment: Yeah since we are still pre-production we solved this with keeping versions at 1.0.0.0 and adding build steps to publish/pull the newest version of each app when needed until we hit production.